# How to Delete Multiple Record using Checkbox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a project for my institute. Using Asp.net MVC, I need multiple delete option with selected checkbox.

I have added a check in my view, but not delete multiple Raw. I don't want to use third party plugin. Please help me.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Select
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Book Id", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.IdSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Title", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Date", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>
            Price
        </th>
        <th>
            Category
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
            Photo
        </th>
        <th>
            User
        </th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="deleteInputs" value="@item.BookId" />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BookId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(item.BookTitle, "Details", new
                {
                    id = item.BookId
                })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PublishDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <img class="img-thumbnail" width="50" height="50" src="~/ContentImages/Full/@item.Photo" />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.BookId })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.BookId })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: So you want to delete rows which are marked by checkbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a way to achieve it:

First embed the table within a named form, that executes the batch delete action, like so:

```
@{ Html.BeginForm("BatchDelete", "Book", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "tableForm" }); }
  <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th>
        Select
      </th>
      <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("Book Id", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.IdSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
      </th>
      <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("Title", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
      </th>
      <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("Date", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
      </th>
      <th>
        Price
      </th>
      <th>
        Category
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
        Photo
      </th>
      <th>
        User
      </th>
      <th>Edit</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="deleteInputs" value="@item.BookId" />
        </td>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BookId)
        </td>
        <td>
          @Html.ActionLink(item.BookTitle, "Details", new
          {
            id = item.BookId
          })
        </td>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PublishDate)
        </td>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </td>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" width="50" height="50" src="~/ContentImages/Full/@item.Photo" />
        </td>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
          @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.BookId })
        </td>
        <td>
          @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.BookId })
        </td>
      </tr>
    }
  </table>

  <!-- Section for buttons -->
  <div class="actions">
      <a href="javascript:(function(){document.tableForm.submit();return void(0);})()">
        Delete selected books
      </a>
  </div>
@{ Html.EndForm(); }
```

Note that after the table, before ending the form, I added a link that executes the submit of the form.

Now, on the controller side, asumming its name is "BookController":

```
public class BookController : Controller
{
    // ...

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult BatchDelete(int[] deleteInputs)
    {
        // You have your books IDs on the deleteInputs array
        if (deleteInputs != null && deleteInputs.Length > 0)
        {
            // If there is any book to delete
            // Perform your delete in the database or datasource HERE
        }
        // And finally, redirect to the action that lists the books
        // (let's assume it's Index)
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // ...
}
```

Notice that:

- The first two parameter of the `Html.BeginForm` method, are the action name and controller name (without the "Controller" suffix).
- The last parameter of the same method include the name of the form. The name is used in the javascript of the link, in order to indicate which form are you going to submit.

Answer (score -1):

First, you need a different `Id` for each checkbox so you know which record is to be deleted. Second, if you implement "delete" as a link then the browser will perform a `GET` action instead of a `POST`. Assuming you are not using `AJAX` then you will need a form so you can `POST` to the controller action which handles the delete.